# Debug NodeJS + ES6 app (Webstorm)

Tags: node.js, webstorm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to use ES6 at both: client and server side. Of course, I can launch my NodeJS server from terminal like `babel-node src/app.js`, but it makes it impossible to debug.

On the other hand Webstorm 9 claims it support ES6, but when I try to launch a default Node configuration it complains about the `a => a + 1` function.

**Question:** How do I launch NodeJS + ES6 app from within Webstorm 9?

P.S. I use Node 0.12.* version
P.S. I also tried [this](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/08/tracing-debugging-and-profiling-node-js-with-spy-js/) but it also doesn't work for me

Comment: Arrow syntax is not yet supported in V8 and hence in NodeJS: https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2700

Comment: @Sirko `babel-node` do parse arrow syntax. Can't I start it from Webstrom?

Comment: you can try specifying it as a node interpreter in your Node.js run configuration. But I'm not sure if debugging will work

Comment: @lena I've specified `/usr/local/bin/babel-node` as Node interpreter - no result

Comment: better now with nodejs at v4.1.1 ?

Comment: @Sirko if you use the module `source-map-support` it works perfect then! :)

Answer (score 5):

I finally got debugging transpiled code with polyfills working in WebStorm, and it's really impressive how well WebStorm works with Babel.

It was pretty easy to follow the directions for configuring a FileWatcher in WebStorm, which automatically transpiles your es6 code:
http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#webstorm

The step that tripped me up was getting node to find the polyfill file, so I could use es6 iterators and generators.  The Babel web site says to install Babel and the polyfill globally:

```
npm install -g babel-es6-polyfill
```

But when I added in my node program:

```
require("babel-es6-polyfill");
```

Node threw an exception about not finding the library.  Then I changed the require path to the exact full path:

```
require("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-es6-polyfill/polyfill.js");
```

and now I can use the debugger to step through the transpiled code!

Comment: I would hope now with nodejs at v4.1.1 these es6 issues previously needing polyfill and babel are moot  ?

Comment: @ScottStensland You'll need babel even with node.js v4.2.0 for es6 features as node.js haven't fully implemented es6 yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below gulp babel task to compile your es6 files into es5. The generated files will be saved in dist directory. Put a breakpoint in the original es6 file eg. app.js and start a debug session for the generated file ie. dist/app.js (since node can’t run es6 files). The breakpoint in the original file will be hit.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel'),
    path = require('path'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util');

// Compile ES6 to ES5
gulp.task("babel", function () {
    return gulp.src('**/*.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(babel())
        .on('error', gutil.log)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {
            includeContent: false,
            sourceRoot: function(file) {
                return path.relative(file.path, __dirname);
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly with 0.12.7. iojs 2 was throwing some errors, buts thats related to a Jetbrains bug.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  Please follow this link, http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling/.  My take is the full ES6 debug support should be seamless but it is not quite there yet in Webstorm.  I'm sure it will get better.  The blog provides a workable solution.  That said, I would rather debug in node-inspector...and Chrome DevTools for React.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/). I did `npm install babel` and add `require('babel/register')` at the beginning of my main node file (`app.js`).

Now I really can launch/debug Node app written with ES6 from Webstorm. But that debugging is something very strange - looks like code that worked before doesn't work know. The Intellij debuger says all my variables are undefined. Also there is [an article](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/481) about another possible problems.

Example:[image]

What is supper fancy about it that inside loop `for (var i = 1; i < trs.length; i++) {` variable `i` considered `undefined`!

Comment: that is to say, it is impossible to debug es6 file in webstorm now, right?

Comment: @HaveF sorry, I'm out of context at the moment, sorry

Comment: Transpile your code with a gulp task instead. Avoid babel/register if you want debugging support.

Comment: Hi, have a look here, I have summarized my setup how to debug ES6 in Webstorm (and for me it works): https://github.com/stefanwalther/es6-debug-webstorm