# Webstorm: Debugging Mocha tests written in ES6

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, webstorm, ecmascript-6

On using WebStorm 10 for Node.js dev, I am unable to step through the test cases (written in ES6) while debugging. I guess the transcompilation is making the test file go out of sync. Wondering if anyone has been able to debug successfully?

Here is my test.js file

```
describe('TestFlow', function () {
    "use strict";

    it('Test Path', (done) => {
        console.log("Testing_1 happy path\n");
        console.log("Testing_2 happy path\n");
        done();
    });
});
```

And I have the Mocha options configured to use **--compilers js:babel/register**. Now when I try to debug the code, the step through process is unpredictable and it just doesn't work. The babel compilation is messing with the debugging process.

Could you please let me know if there is a work around to this issue? I thought the debugging ES6 code was a feature in WebStrom 10, but I have not had luck with it

Comment: Yes, I am having the same issue. You should open a ticket with JetBrains.

Comment: done https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/465474?tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

This works now in at least WebStorm 2017.1.  JetBrains has marked [this issue as fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16397)

From terminal:

```
> npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-preset-es2015
```

Under the menu Run/Edit Configurations...Mocha Run/Debug configuration, enter this option:

```
Extra Mocha options: --compilers js:babel-core/register
```

Also, have a .babelrc file (or put in package.json)

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

You should now be able to run and debug your ES6 unit tests
See [this article as well](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/using-mocha-with-es6-spec-files)

Answer (score 1):

Webstorm debugger won't work with runtime babel compilation. You need to first compile your ES6 files using babel with sourcemaps and place them let's say in *dist* directory. You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33045275/825980) gulp task to do so.

In webstorm's debug mocha configuration point working directory to the above created *dist* directory. Also point test directory to your tests in *dist* directory. Put a breakpoint in the original ES6 test file and start your debug session.

Comment: did what you said but it keeps trying to put a breakpoint in the transpiled files.  I did set my working dir and test dir to the dist folder and it won't break on the original files, only transpiled

Answer (score 0):

In WebStorm go to **Run/Edit Configurations.../Templates/Mocha/Extra Mocha options** and insert the following (depends on version of babel: https://git.io/vdcSr).

### Babel 7

```
--require @babel/register
```

### Babel 6

```
--require babel-core/register
```