# WebStorm not recognizing Javascript "for...of..." structure

Tags: javascript, for-loop, webstorm

I'm new to WebStorm and I'm writing a pretty simple piece of Javascript to loop through a list of JSON objects. The objects are pulled from a JSON file using d3. The code is:

```
allNodes; //list of JSON objects 
for (let node of allNodes) {
     console.log(node);
}
```

The code works fine, but WebStorm underlines much of it in red, saying "expected 'in' or ';'".

Comment: Change the ES version from _settings->JavaScript->Language version_

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170589/debug-nodejs-es6-app-webstorm

Comment: @RayonDabre please move your question to answer.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Using `let` and for/of statements in JavaScript are fairly new (`let` is new to EMCAscript6/ES6/Harmony) and are not widely supported (Internet Explorer, for example). It is better to use this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < allNodes.length; i++) {
    console.log(allNodes[i]);
}
```

Comment: What about using `for...in...`? Is the traditional for loop still preferable to this?

Comment: The question was not about IE support of ES6 new features. Maybe topic-starter uses Babel or other transpiler? Please, don't get off topic

Comment: @ManasovDaniel I was using IE as an example of incompatibility and the fact that ES6 is not fully compatible with many compilers.

Comment: @user2740614 for/in should work fine, but sticking to traditional styles will produce the best outcomes.

Comment: Actually, it's supported in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, node, and more importantly Babel which can transpile into ES5 which runs anywhere, and there's no reason for the OP not to use it, and the answer he is looking for is how to tell his IDE to stop complaining about it, not some advice about returning to the past.